# rank inequality for Hadamard product

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, hadamard-product

How I can show that

$$
\operatorname{rank}(A\circ B) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A)\operatorname{rank}(B)
$$

where $A,B$ are rectangular matrices and $\circ$ is the Hadamard product between the two.

Similarly, how can we show that  if $A$ has rank d, then $\operatorname{rank}(A\circ A)$ is at most $d+1 \choose 2$ ?

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the question is well covered in the other [question on Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/812556/332683). To prove $\text{rank}\left(A\circ A\right)\leq {{d+1}\choose 2}$, we should specialize the derivation in the aforementioned question:

Writing matrix $A$ as a sum of rank-one matrices:
$$
A=\sum_{i=1}^{d}p_iq_i^*
$$
results in
$$
A\circ A = \sum_{i=1}^{d}\sum_{j=1}^{d}(p_i\circ p_j)(q_i\circ q_j)^*.
$$
For this particular case, we can make a bound a bit tighter compared to a general case. To determine the bound on the $\text{rank}(A\circ A)$, we need to find the max number of distinct rank-1 matrices, which would follow a simple combinatoric formula *choose $n$ from $k$ with repetitions*:

$$
\text{rank}(A\circ A)\leq {d+2-1 \choose 2} \leq {d+1 \choose 2}.
$$